# Batch processing stdin lines with Windows batch .bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, shell-script

I have a Windows batch script `delete.bat` with that contents:

```
@echo off
takeown.exe /A /R /F %1
icacls %1 /grant Administrators:(OI)(CI)F /C /T /Q /L
rmdir /S /Q %1
echo %cd%\%1 >> "C:\delete.txt"
```

Now I want to pass a txt file to that script like `delete.bat < C:\delete.txt` and the script must process each line of stdin like parameter `%1`.

How can I make a `while(!feof(stdin))` and `var line = fgets(stdin)` and then replace `%1` with `%line%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the
[FOR /F command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html),
described as :

> Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.

Example : Copy the files listed in a text file to a new destination:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (files.txt) DO copy "\\source\folder\%%G" "H:\destination\%%G"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating a list of files, generate a list of batch commands:

```
echo del "%cd%\%~1" >> "C:\delete.bat"
```

Then just run the file as a batch script.